# Automatic click on ListView if has only one item

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I am trying to search for some data in Mysql database, then display it Listview

When more than 1 result is found, clicking on any one of them will take you to its respective details page.

But.. I am looking to go to details page directly if there is only one result in list view. Put simply,  how would I call onItemClick on the list view automatically when there is only one item in the list.

My Listview's onClickItemListener looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    // when a student is selected then the following methods are called

    DetailsFragment.setLUNCH_TYPE(searchResult.get(position).lunchtype);
    Log.d("Lunch type selected", ""+DetailsFragment.getLUNCH_TYPE());
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).startStudentSale(searchResult
            .get(position).name.toString(),searchResult
            .get(position).isStudent,searchResult.get(position).id);

    // it was comming null here when running this this need to find out why
    // ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).setmSaleType(SALE_TYPE.SEARCHED_STUDENT);
}
```

Comment: you need not call onclick for that simply check your data source for size and if size == 1 then just call method which is ur calling from onclick.

Comment: Doing so giving me illegalstateexception

Comment: did i need to call super.onBackPressed(); to hide the fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know the count of the resultSet, say cnt and if it is 1, i.e.

```
  if(cnt==1){
   Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: Doing so giving me illegalstateexception

Comment: did i need to call super.onBackPressed(); to hide the fragment ?

Comment: in which part of your prog are you doing this?

Comment: thanks , it is working now . do you have any idea how to stop the asynctaskloader or reset the asynctask loader ?